# How to select second last row of a pandas dataframe using iloc[]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, row

I fetch the data from online and store that data in a pandas dataframe. But the problem is the dataframe format is not same every time mainly numbers of rows.

```
Print(df.shape)
Output: (100, 9)
```

--

```
Print(df.shape)
Output: (33, 9)
```

--

```
Print(df.shape)
Output: (153, 9)
```

--

```
Print(df.shape)
Output: (148, 9)
```

Can you please tell me how we can select only second last row or second last row’s any specific cell using iloc[]

Comment: `df.iloc[[-2]]` ?

Comment: And sir if i want to select second last row's second column then i have to use `df.iloc[[-2],[1]]` am i right sir???

Comment: `df.iloc[-2,1]` sould do what you need

Answer (score 8):

`df.iloc[-2]` will get you the penultimate row info for all columns.

If you want a specific column only, `df.loc` doesn't like the minus sign, so one way you could do it would be: `df.loc[(df.shape[0]-2), 'your_column_name']`

Where `df.shape[0]` gets your row count, and -2 removes 2 from it to give you the index number for your penultimate row. Then you give it the required column name to only return that value.

Comment: Doesn't like the minus sign - how strange - is there a good reason for that do you know?

Comment: @jtlz2 poor phrasing perhaps, I should've said it just doesn't accept indexing in that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`take`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.take.html):

```
# all columns
df.take([-2])

# specific column
df['foo'].take([-2])
```

Comment: Been using pandas for 7 years, never even knew about "take", thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the second row from the back using index -2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4; 5 6')
p = pd.DataFrame(a)
print("dataframe\n" + str(p))

print("second last row\n" + str(np.array(p.iloc[-2])))
```

Output:

```
dataframe
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6

second last row
[3 4]
```