# Selecting second last row in pandas after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import yfinance as yf
import datetime 

ticker = 'f'
df = yf.download(tickers = ticker, start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=6), end= datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m", progress = False)
df['day'] = df.index.day
df['pClose'] = df.groupby('day').nth(-2)['Close']
```

So with `df['pClose'] = df.groupby('day').nth(-2)['Close']` I am trying to select the second last row. But it is producing this:

```
       Open   High    Low   Close  Adj Close   Volume  pClose
day                                                          
7    13.740  13.77  13.74  13.755     13.755  1451751     NaN
8    13.540  13.56  13.52  13.540     13.540  1199373     NaN
9    13.340  13.35  13.32  13.335     13.335  1399753     NaN
10   12.765  12.78  12.74  12.745     12.745  2398719     NaN
```

Could you please advise why it is not selecting the second last row?

---

### Edit

To get the previous days's closing price: `df = yf.download(tickers = ticker, start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=6), end= datetime.datetime.now(), progress = False)`

Where `ticker = "f"`

```
             Open   High    Low  Close  Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                       
2022-06-07  13.26  13.77  13.19  13.74      13.74  38940300
2022-06-08  13.63  13.85  13.44  13.53      13.53  39441900
2022-06-09  13.51  13.59  13.28  13.28      13.28  30468000
2022-06-10  13.00  13.21  12.63  12.75      12.75  55644400
```

So on 9th the closing price was 13.28. However this is on a daily interval, in the code above not specifying interval defaults to daily.

Since the dataframe which I am requesting is on 5 min interval.

```
                              Open     High  ...  Adj Close   Volume
Datetime                                     ...                    
2022-06-07 09:30:00-04:00  13.2600  13.3800  ...    13.3700  2543171
2022-06-07 09:35:00-04:00  13.3679  13.4200  ...    13.3426   712259
2022-06-07 09:40:00-04:00  13.3500  13.3550  ...    13.2900   509699
2022-06-07 09:45:00-04:00  13.2900  13.3382  ...    13.3300   451413
2022-06-07 09:50:00-04:00  13.3300  13.4100  ...    13.3801   849915
                           ...      ...  ...        ...      ...
2022-06-10 15:40:00-04:00  12.8050  12.8100  ...    12.7801   889435
2022-06-10 15:45:00-04:00  12.7850  12.7900  ...    12.7400  1469980
2022-06-10 15:50:00-04:00  12.7450  12.7800  ...    12.7650  1910267
2022-06-10 15:55:00-04:00  12.7650  12.7800  ...    12.7450  2398719
2022-06-10 16:00:00-04:00  12.7500  12.7500  ...    12.7500        0
```

What I am trying to do groupby all the data on day number with `datatime.index.day` and then access the closing price on the second last day`. This is where the problem was as when i did` .nth(-2)['Close']` It was not selecting just 1 row, but was returning all the days available

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select second last row of a pandas dataframe using iloc\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818878/how-to-select-second-last-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe-using-iloc)

Comment: I tried using iloc. `df.groupby('day').iloc[-2]` But it gives `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'iloc'` error

Answer (score 2):

When you assign in pandas, there's this thing called index-matching where the values are assigned to the matching index of the assigned `df`.

You code returns:

```
>>> df.groupby('day').nth(-2)['Close']
day
7     13.755
8     13.540
9     13.335
10    12.745
```

where the indexes are days. However, the original `df` has datetime indexes:

```
                             Open     High      Low    Close  Adj Close  
Datetime                                                                   
2022-06-07 09:30:00-04:00  13.2600  13.3800  13.1850  13.3700    13.3700   
2022-06-07 09:35:00-04:00  13.3679  13.4200  13.2900  13.3426    13.3426   
2022-06-07 09:40:00-04:00  13.3500  13.3550  13.2800  13.2900    13.2900   
2022-06-07 09:45:00-04:00  13.2900  13.3382  13.2701  13.3300    13.3300   
2022-06-07 09:50:00-04:00  13.3300  13.4100  13.3100  13.3801    13.3801
```

That way, none of them match, so all values end up being `NaN`s.

Here, use `transform` to keep the same original indexes and broadcast the values:

```
>>> df.groupby('day').Close.transform('nth', n=-2)

Datetime
2022-06-07 09:30:00-04:00    13.290
2022-06-07 09:35:00-04:00    13.290
2022-06-07 09:40:00-04:00    13.290
2022-06-07 09:45:00-04:00    13.290
2022-06-07 09:50:00-04:00    13.290
                              ...  
2022-06-10 15:40:00-04:00    13.205
2022-06-10 15:45:00-04:00    13.205
2022-06-10 15:50:00-04:00    13.205
2022-06-10 15:55:00-04:00    13.205
2022-06-10 16:00:00-04:00    13.205
```

---

To get the previous day close, you can just use `loc`

```
>>> df.loc[df['day'] == df['day'].max() - 1, 'Close'].tail(1)
```

Comment: Since the last date was 10, how can I access the last Close on 09? Since even with specifying `n=2` it is returning all the dates. Thanks

Comment: So I am trying to select the second last row after grouping by day. Since the data is in 5 min interval. Thus after groupby day, i am trying to find the last entry of `Close` in second last date. In this case the second last date would be 9.

Comment: So whichever day i get the data of, I am trying to get previous closing price. That was what i was trying to accomplish with grouping 5 min data on `day`

Comment: give me a sec, i will update the question.

Comment: Please see my original question for the edit. Please disregard the edit I made by mistake on your answer

Comment: @Slartibartfast see last line of code in my answer.

Comment: By explicating saying '-1', it dosent work for Mondays. How can i get the second last available date from the index?

Answer (score 0):

Are you okay with resetting the index?
Then you can try something as such

```
ticker = 'f'
df = yf.download(tickers = ticker, start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=6), end= datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m", progress = False)
df['day'] = df.index.day
df['pClose'] = df.groupby('day')
df = df.reset_index()
df2 = df.iloc[-2]
```